# magento 1.9.2 displays base currency as display currency

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency

I am setting up Magento e-Commerce 1.9.2 for my client. he is located in UAE and wants to use Paypal for transactions. As AED is not supported by Paypal so I am using US Dollars as Base currency and AED as default Display Currency.

Now the issue is magento displays base currency on the front-end instead of Default Display Currency.

so Please if you can help me with that.